# Error loading operating system from USB

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, operating-systems

I am trying to load Windows 10 to a blank Dell hard drive, but this error keeps popping up:

[image: Error loading operating system]

- I have already updated the BIOS

[image: updated BIOS]

- I have already ran a diagnostic and came out clean

[image: ![basic diagnostic]

Comment: your intentions are a bit unclear. Did you mean you want to use the USB as an installation environment to install to the Dell hard drive? If this is the case there could be a number of problems ranging from incorrect file system format (NTFS vs FAT32 vs EXFAT), are you choosing to boot from USB in your bios, Are you trying to boot in EUFI mode which you are confusing with BIOS (Sometimes you will have an option to go into  "Legacy Mode" , and much more. I would double check that you aren't having an issue with your overall process!

Comment: @RickwhoPrograms Yes, that is what I am going for. I'm using EXFAT, and I am choosing boot from USB.

Comment: @Ramhound When I tried that, nothing shows up. I am unable to add any booting devices.

Comment: You don't need to add any boot devices.  All the boot devices you need are listed, you just need to remove, all the invalid boot devices and change the order of the devices list in addition to use FAT32 instead of EXFAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to load Windows 10 to a blank Dell hard drive, but this error keeps popping up.  I'm using EXFAT, and I am choosing boot from USB.

You cannot install Windows from any media with a EXFAT partition.  You have created your installation Media the incorrect way.  Use the Media Creation Tool.  Windows can only be installed from a FAT32 partition.